# How to create react native layout

Tags: react-native

I am new for react native, and recently I want to develop an app with below layout, but I have no idea how to build it.

```
Row1 (contain only one column)
column1  | column2 (Row 2 with 2 columns)
Row3  (Row 3 with one column)
```

Comment: Use flexbox for this layout

Comment: @RaajNadar can you please provide some example?

Answer (score 0):

React Native uses flexbox to handle layout matters

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html

In your case, you could try something like this:

```
<View
  style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }} // it will display the direct children as columns, instead of rows, so they will be one below the other
>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}> // it will ocupies the full width
    <Text>Line with single content</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' }}> // it will ocupies the cull width and distribute the same width amoung for all direct children
    <Text>This content goes left</Text>
    <Text>This content goes right</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}> // it will ocupies the full width
    <Text>Last line with single content</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Take this code just as an example to express the idea, I wrote it here in the comment, so there might be typos.

This is a cool game based tutorial to learn more about flexbox: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Hope it helps